# Join on specific columns using Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to do join some tables on specific columns using Sequelize.js.

So far, my code is something like:

```
table_1.findall({
  include: [{
    model: table_2
    attributes: ['id', 'another_id']
    include: [{
      model: table_3
      required: true
      attributes: ['time']
    }]
  }]
})
```

where each table's primary key is 'id'.

This seems to be equivalent to the following SQL (I am showing SELECT * for brevity, since that is not the focus of this question):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
INNER JOIN table_3 as t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id
```

and I want to have something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
INNER JOIN table_3 as t3 ON t2.another_id = t3.t2_id
```

Is there a way to force the join between t2 and t3 to use something either than the primary key of t2?

I have found the [options.include[].on]
in the [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance), but do not know what the syntax is for suppling my own ON condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to define the special case foreign key name in the associations themselves, defined in the `classMethods` section of your models. Here's an example of a table that joins to the `users` table twice, with specially named foreign keys:

```
classMethods: {
  associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: 'created_by_user_id',
      as: 'created_by',
    });
    this.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: 'updated_by_user_id',
      as: 'updated_by',
    });
  },
},
```

Then, in your `findAll`, there's no need to do anything special - sequelize will know what foreign key column to use automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mention like this in you code/controller file:

```
const storeModel = model.store;
const bookedTicketModel = model.booked_ticket;
bookedTicketModel.belongsTo (storeModel, {foreignKey: 'storeId'});
storeModel.hasMany (bookedTicketModel, {foreignKey: 'id'});
```